# OpenGL "black screen" frustration

Tags: c++, c, qt, opengl

I am still trying to figure out, why i see only typical "black screen". I render just one rectangle, but nothing happened.

```
#include "expwidget.h"
#include <iostream>

ExpWidget::ExpWidget(QObject *parent) :
    QGLWidget(QGLFormat(QGL::DoubleBuffer), (QWidget *) parent)
{

    QGLFormat fmt = this->format();
    fmt.setDepth(true);

    this->setFormat(fmt);
}



void ExpWidget::initializeGL() {

    QGLWidget::initializeGL(); 

    std::cout << "inicializace...\n";

    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

}


void ExpWidget::paintGL() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f(1, 0, .5);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-5.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,-1.0f,-5.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f,1.0f,-5.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,1.0f,-5.0f);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();


}

void ExpWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {

    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glFrustum(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 0.0, -30.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);


}
```

Comment: The initializations you make in `initializeGL()` do not seem to be complete. Try calling `QGLWidget::initializeGL();` in your `initializeGL()` before any other openGL commands. Qt's default implementation of `initializeGL()` should do the rest of the work :)

Comment: @maddin45: didn't work :(

Comment: Too bad. Another guess: How are your lights set up? I don't see any lighting setup in your code. Without light, everything is black. Or is lighting completely disabled?

Comment: @maddin45: disabled :/

Comment: Use graphics debugger

Comment: Remember that `QOpenGLDebugLogger` is your friend. Create an instance of it in the ctor, `initialize()` it in `initializeGL`, connect its `messageLogged` signal to a private slot of yours and then `startLogging()`. You'll immediately get messages such: `QOpenGLDebugMessage("APISource", 1281, "GL_INVALID_VALUE error generated. <zNear> and <zFar> must be positive nonequal values, <right> and <left> must not be equal, and <top> and <bottom> must not be equal.", "HighSeverity", "ErrorType") ` , and the backtrace will tell you that `glFrustum` is generating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced a similar problem in the past, but I don't claim to be an expert.

Calls to `glFrustum` are in the form `glFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far)`

`near` and `far` must both be positive and non-zero. (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml)

so in your case I would recommend changing your call to:

```
glFrustum(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 30.0);
```

Also, your coordinates should have negative Z to render in this view.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFrustum.xml:

`nearVal, farVal`

`Specify the distances to the near and far depth clipping planes. Both distances must be positive.`